# AngularJS button click not triggering function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to modify this: https://github.com/amirrajan/nodejs-against-humanity

To work with the rules of a game I made up. One of the most significant parts is that, instead of white cards, there should be a single text box with a button to submit. When I press submit, nothing happens - The Javascript alert doesn't fire or anything.

game.html:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="showWhiteCardList()">
  <table id="whiteCards" class="table">
    <tbody id="whiteCardSelection">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <textarea ng-model="situationAppendage"></textarea>
          <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="selectSituation(situationAppendage)">Submit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

services.js:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
  .factory('GameService', function($http) {
        var s4 = function() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x10000).toString();
        };
        var guid = function(){
            return s4() + s4() + "-" + s4() + "-" + s4() + "-" + s4() + "-" + s4() + s4() + s4();
        };
        var pId = guid();

        return {
            playerName: '',
            playerId : pId,
            newGameId : guid(),
            currentGameId: undefined,
            initName: function() {
                if(this.playerName.length === 0) {
                    this.playerName = 'anonymous ' + s4();
                }
            },
            getGames: function() {
                return $http.get('/list');
            },
            createGame: function() {
                return $http.post('/add', { id: guid(), name: this.playerName + "'s game" });
            },
            joinGame: function(gameId, playerId, name) {
                return $http.post("/joingame", { gameId: gameId, playerId: playerId, playerName: name });
            },
            departGame: function(gameId, playerId) {
                $http.post('/departgame', { gameId: gameId, playerId: playerId});
            },
            selectCard: function(gameId, playerId, selectedCard){
                $http.post("/selectCard", { gameId: gameId, playerId: playerId, whiteCardId: selectedCard });
            },
            selectSituation: function(gameId, playerId, textBoxText){
                $http.post("/selectSituation", { gameId: gameId, playerId: playerId, textBoxText : textBoxText });
            },
            selectWinner: function(gameId, selectedCard) {
                $http.post("/selectWinner", { gameId: gameId, cardId: selectedCard });
            },
            readyForNextRound: function(gameId, playerId) {
                $http.post("readyForNextRound",  { playerId: playerId, gameId: gameId });
            }
        };
    });
```

controllers.js:

```
$scope.selectSituaton = function(textToAppend) {
  alert('Situation fired');
  GameService.selectSituaton($scope.gameId, $scope.playerId, textToAppend);
};
```

server.js:

```
app.post('/selectSituation', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Triggered");
  Game.selectSituation(req.body.gameId, req.body.playerId, req.body.textBoxText);
  broadcastGame(req.body.gameId);
  returnGame(req.body.gameId, res);
});
```

I'm new to Node.JS, AngularJS, and Javascript, so I'm probably missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I suppose you have `ng-controller` and `ng-app` somewhere, right? Have you set a breakpoint in your controller to see that it is loading it?

Comment: No, that must be it. Where do they go? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Can you please provide jsfiddle or plunker for your problem?

Comment: `ng-app` can go in the `body` tag. `ng-controller` should probably be in the outermost `div` element so that it encloses all elements with function calls

Comment: @mparnisari In game.html, right?

Comment: @mparnisari Nope, didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues is **typo error with selectSituation** in controller. For now it is **$scope.selectSituaton** while it should be **$scope.selectSituation**.

Try with below code:

```
$scope.selectSituation = function(textToAppend) {
  alert('Situation fired');
  GameService.selectSituaton($scope.gameId, $scope.playerId, textToAppend);
};
```

I believe it will resolve your issue.

Cheers!